# Why ( new Date() ).toString() is so slow in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, date, tostring

I am playing a bit with Node.js. I've just started writing something new and it stuck me that my simple "console" app takes quite long to respond. This app loads a 5MB json file, turns it into an object but all that still does not take a significant amount of time. My further search (in a quite short and simple code) led me to conclusion that this single line:

```
this.generated_on = ( new Date() ).toString();
```

takes around 2.5s to execute. Further investigation made me understand even less. I've modified it to:

```
this.generated_on = new Date();
this.generated_on = this.generated_on.toString();
```

(with console.timeLogs  in between) and line with `toString()` was the one that took over 2 seconds to execute. Then, I've modified the code once again:

```
this.generated_on = new Date('2019-02-04 20:00:00');
this.generated_on = this.generated_on.toString();
```

and results were other way around. `toString()` took only 2ms while creating `Date` object took over 2s.

Why is it so slow? Why so different results? Any faster way to get formatted current time string? (I don't care much about execution time for this project as it works offline, still it bugs me).

Comment: FWIW, this operation is small milliseconds on my box.  You may be mis-identifying the problem.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Do you have any actual code to share? Creating a date object is really fast

Comment: I have little experience in Node.js but this doesn't seem like general behaviour. First thoughts are some odd package messing with `Date` or Node having trouble getting data from the underlying system. Maybe someone with more experience can quickly answer it but I think it's useful to give more information. Exact Node.js version and packages and maybe more of your code to actually be able to replicate the issue. - edit - or what Paul is saying =)

Comment: I am using 2 libs: `fs` (obviously) and ECT (templating). Actually, second one is not used yet, only required. @Rene might be right. I am using node on ubuntu on windows 10 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your development environment is off or something. I cannot tell you why your machine is running the code in a slow manner. I cannot replicate the problem you were saying.

I tried to benchmark the code you have above.

https://repl.it/@act/HotpinkFearfulActiveserverpages

Go here and try clicking on Run button at the top.

Here's the result I am seeing

```
// Case Togehter: 
// this.generated_on = ( new Date() ).toString();
// Case Separately:
// this.generated_on = new Date();
// this.generated_on = this.generated_on.toString();

Together x 332,222 ops/sec ±7.75% (44 runs sampled)
Separtely x 313,162 ops/sec ±8.48% (43 runs sampled)
```

332,222 ops/sec means an operation took 1/332,222 seconds on average.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use node.js builtin module 'Performance hooks'.

You can find documentation here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_mark_name

Mark each process from top to bottom and then print the metrics (in milliseconds), you will figure out the actual issue